# redirect subdomain and paths to another domain on apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following two rules in my htaccess file on domain1.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain2\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://{%1.}domain2.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

It should redirect the following scenarios:

```
http://www.domain1.com/ --> http://domain2.com/
http://domain1.com/ --> http://domain2.com/
http://domain1.com/hello-world/ --> http://domain2.com/hello-world/
http://hello.domain1.com/ --> http://hello.domain2.com/
http://hello.domain1.com/world/ --> http://hello.domain2.com/world/
```

The first three work fine, but the ones with the subdomain don't redirect.

Comment: "The first three work fine" - then there must be something else doing the redirecting. The directives you have posted cannot possibly work. **1)** You say this is on `domain1`, yet your condition states `domain2`? **2)** You have curly braces in your `RewriteRule` substitution that will break any kind of redirect/rewrite? **3)** Whilst not an error, you don't include the `R` flag for an explicit redirect. Because you specify a protocol in the substitution you'll get an _implicit_ redirect. It's better being explicit.

Comment: @w3d actually you are right they don't work. Seems the redirect was cached. Could you post what the correct solution would be? Thanks.

Comment: Do `domain1` and `domain2` point to the same place on the filesystem? (If not then the additional condition is not required.) Do you have a wildcard subdomain configured in the DNS for both domains?

Comment: No they are diff places. Everything from domain1 should redirect to domain2 exactly as is except swapping the domain itself.

Comment: I'll only be switching the wildcard off on domain2 as I'll want domain1 to catch everything still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1domain2.com/$1 [L]
```